# Rails: One model for Authentication and Profile information or 2 separate models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, model, profile

In many tutorials (especially for authentication), speakers say to put user authentication and profile information in the same table (model) called User.

**My question is simple: Is it safe to put everything in one table? (bonus: is this the best practice?)**

I would rather suggest to separate authentication information (email, password, salt,...) and profile information (first name, last name, birth day, location, gender,...) in two models: User (for authentication) and Profile, and linking models by has_one/belongs_to associations.

**Am I wrong? What do you suggest me?**

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this question helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555686/advantages-of-having-user-authentication-details-stored-in-a-separate-table

Answer (score 6):

If you want to follow [database normalisations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) you should separate the tables. However, sometimes it is not the best option... For example, if your table `users` has just `email`, `password` (for authentication) and `name`. I won't create a `profile` table just  to store the `name`, right?

So, it will depend on your requirements to make your design decisions....

I found [this interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889797/mysql-user-profile-details-table-setup-best-practice) about it, where @D Roddis explain some advantages and disadvantages about three different approaches: `Storing User Profile in Users Table`, `Storing User Profile in User_Profile Table 1-1 relationship to users` and `Storing User Profile as properties and values in tables`.

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

I'd put them in seperate models myself.

How many actions are there which operate on user and profile together? Not many, There are a lot in both constructs where they need to know nothing (or nothing more than the id) about each other.